# GUnicorn throws error while loading python flask app: no such option as -b

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

```
    #:return: Flask app
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

GUnicorn start command:-

```
gunicorn "app:app" -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Error:-

```
[2020-04-06 12:35:09 +0000] [62] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 62)
[2020-04-06 12:35:09 +0000] [63] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63
Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS]
Try 'gunicorn --help' for help.
Error: no such option: -b
```

The GUnicorn goes in an infinite loop while starting up. Can someone please explain me what I'm missing?

Comment: The python file is app.py. Currently I'm starting the app in Dev mode by a simple python app.py.

Comment: * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 818-356-890

Comment: I'm running the app on a container over k8s. Have already set the FLASK_APP=app env.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around "app:app"

Comment: @DanSafee Actually the start up command is inside an entrypoint.sh, thus the quotes. Should not be a problem right?

Comment: @DanSafee No, removing the quotes didn't work. :(